# Switch fluentd to Stackdriver logging API v2

Tags: logging, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, fluentd, stackdriver

We've got a Google Compute Engine webserver running Ubuntu on Google Cloud Platform, which sends logs to the Stackdriver Logging API "v1beta"

We received emails from Google Cloud Platform about the Stackdriver Logging API v1beta3 deprecation, alerting us that our "project" is still accessing the v1 API, and advising us to switch to the v2 API. The email advised upgrading the Stackdriver Logging Agent (fluentd), which I have done.

If I try to send a log item from the command line on that server:

```
logger "Hello world!"
```

It still appears in the Stackdriver Log in the v1 API format (with `metadata.projectId`, `metaData.serviceName`, etc.)

How can I configure fluentd to hit the v2 API instead of the deprecated v1 API? I have to update all the logging integration in the apps on this server, but I can't see where or how to get the logging agent to use the new API.

Answer (score 0):

Are you viewing the logs in the Stackdriver UI? Because the [migration page](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/v2/migration-to-v2) says that Log Viewer currently displays everything in v1 format even if it's v2.

> *The Logs Viewer presently uses only the v1 API. In the future, there will be support for the v2 API, but for now the limitation might be a hindrance to your migration...*

Comment: I am; I don't know where else I can view the entries sent to Slackdriver. I thought I had read that the Logs Viewer would start displaying v2 some time in October, but now it's saying "in the future"